# How to Call/Require Ruby 1.8 Lib from Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I'm using a Ruby 1.8 lib `kakasi-ruby`, but it seems that it can only be compiled against Ruby 1.8 (https://github.com/hogelog/kakasi-ruby/issues/2)

My application is Ruby 1.9.3, so I need to call `kakasi-ruby` from Ruby 1.9.3.

How should I do?

Do I have to open a subprocess with Ruby 1.8, and wait for it finish to get the process return value?

Edit:
https://github.com/hogelog/kakasi-ruby

Comment: Could you provide a link to the library you are using? Maybe there is an alternative that is working with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found 3 possible paths:

- There seems to be a [branch for 1.9](https://github.com/hogelog/kakasi-ruby/tree/1.9) in the repo. Maybe try to compile that instead?
- Otherwise your fastest option is probably to go back to 1.8 depending on what kind of app it is.
- Calling with 1.8 may work BUT since the library seems to be a binding to some C code you could probably call that code directly just as well.

Comment: Great, the branch 1.9 works.  BTW, we need to be very careful about encoding.  I added my own answer to clarify how to use the 1.9 branch.

Comment: BTW, do you know how to convert it to a customized gem? so that I could put them under `RoR_Root/vendor/gems/`?

Comment: Not sure when there is native code in it. I have been using the gem jeweler to create pure Ruby gems and it is really easy. It gives you a couple of rake tasks and off you go. What you need is probably a gemspec file and I suspect you may get away with just copying the code with the gemspec file to your RoR directory. (Or - you could point to a fork with a gemspec - would be preferable for several reasons: others may need your work and you avoid having local gems laying around.)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, here is the usage in Ruby 1.9

```
plee@sos:~/Japanese$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'kakasi'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :002 > src="前原誠司経済財政相は４日、朝日新聞などのインタビューに対し"
 => "前原誠司経済財政相は４日、朝日新聞などのインタビューに対し" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > src=src.encode("EUC-JP", "UTF-8")
 => "\x{C1B0}\x{B8B6}\x{C0BF}\x{BBCA}\x{B7D0}\x{BAD1}\x{BAE2}\x{C0AF}\x{C1EA}\x{A4CF}\x{A3B4}\x{C6FC}\x{A1A2}\x{C4AB}\x{C6FC}\x{BFB7}\x{CAB9}\x{A4CA}\x{A4C9}\x{A4CE}\x{A5A4}\x{A5F3}\x{A5BF}\x{A5D3}\x{A5E5}\x{A1BC}\x{A4CB}\x{C2D0}\x{A4B7}" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > dst=Kakasi.kakasi("-w", src)
 => "\xC1\xB0\xB8\xB6 \xC0\xBF\xBB\xCA \xB7\xD0\xBA\xD1 \xBA\xE2\xC0\xAF \xC1\xEA \xA4\xCF \xA3\xB4 \xC6\xFC \xA1\xA2 \xC4\xAB\xC6\xFC\xBF\xB7\xCA\xB9 \xA4\xCA\xA4\xC9\xA4\xCE \xA5\xA4\xA5\xF3\xA5\xBF\xA5\xD3\xA5\xE5\xA1\xBC \xA4\xCB \xC2\xD0\xA4\xB7" 
1.9.3p194 :005 > dst.force_encoding("EUC-JP")
 => "\x{C1B0}\x{B8B6} \x{C0BF}\x{BBCA} \x{B7D0}\x{BAD1} \x{BAE2}\x{C0AF} \x{C1EA} \x{A4CF} \x{A3B4} \x{C6FC} \x{A1A2} \x{C4AB}\x{C6FC}\x{BFB7}\x{CAB9} \x{A4CA}\x{A4C9}\x{A4CE} \x{A5A4}\x{A5F3}\x{A5BF}\x{A5D3}\x{A5E5}\x{A1BC} \x{A4CB} \x{C2D0}\x{A4B7}" 
1.9.3p194 :006 > dst=dst.encode("UTF-8", "EUC-JP")
 => "前原 誠司 経済 財政 相 は ４ 日 、 朝日新聞 などの インタビュー に 対し" 
1.9.3p194 :007 >
```